# If statement within JavaScript function not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have the following function

```
var VisibilityNewDevice = 1
function visibilityNewDevice() {
    if (VisibilityNewDevice === 1) {
         toggleVisibility('buttonPressesTable'),
         toggleVisibility('IconMinimize'),
         toggleVisibility('IconSync'); 
         var VisibilityNewDevice = 0;
    }
}
```

Which if I call `visibilityNewDevice()` I get `undefined` returned and doesn't run the code. However if I run the like this

```
if (VisibilityNewDevice === 1) {
    toggleVisibility('buttonPressesTable'),
    toggleVisibility('IconMinimize'), 
    toggleVisibility('IconSync'); 
    var VisibilityNewDevice = 0;
}
```

It works fine. I'm confused why the `function` doesn't work, but when I run the `if` statement it works fine.

Comment: var hoisting: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Comment: Always be aware of global variables declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The answer is to simply **remove the `var`** inside the function

You write

```
var VisibilityNewDevice = 1
function visibilityNewDevice() {
  // expecting: 1 === 1
  if (VisibilityNewDevice === 1) {
     ...
     var VisibilityNewDevice = 0;
  }
}
```

Javascript compiles

```
var VisibilityNewDevice = 1
function visibilityNewDevice() {
    var VisibilityNewDevice = undefined;

    // undefined === 1
    if (VisibilityNewDevice === 1) {
     ... 
     VisibilityNewDevice = 0;
   }
}
```

Notice your `var` is **hoisted** at the top, that goes for any `var` you create inside the `function`. That **hoisted** `var` will overwrite any global `var` with the same name when the program enters the `function`.

See also: [JavaScript Hoisting Explained](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-hoisting-explained--net-15092)

Finally when your create private `var` its not a bad idea to **hoist** it your self so you can follow your code better

```
function () {
    var a, b, c, d;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function tries to define the variable again.

Your

`var VisibilityNewDevice = 0;`

at the end of the function should be

`VisibilityNewDevice = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

its not working because youre calling `var VisibilityNewDevice = 0;`. specifically the `var`. that means the `VisibilityNewDevice` in your if statement is not referencing your outer variable, its referencing the inner one, which is `undefined` at the time of execution.

removing the `var` in the if statement should get this working

Answer (score 1):

By having

```
var VisibilityNewDevice;
```

you've declared local variable VisibilityNewDevice inside the function. By having

```
var VisibilityNewDevice = 0;
```

you are setting that **local** variable to zero. Not the outer one as you need.

Answer (score 0):

This is call variable hoisting.

```
var x = 1;

function test(){
   console.log(x);
   var x = 3;
}

test();
```

this is same as

```
function test(){
       var x;
       console.log(x);
       x = 3;
    }
```